# How to change property for all items in list using expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I need to implement following function:

```
List<T> Set<T, TV>(
    List<T> items, Expression<Func<T, TV>> extract, Expression<Func<T, TV>> update);
```

So it would work like this:

```
List<Item> listOfModifiedItems =
    d.Set(listOfItems, i => i.SomeBooleanProperty, s => false );
```

As a result we would have `listOfModifiedItems` where all items have `SomeBooleanProperty` changed to false.
I just don't understand how to properly do it.

Comment: What is purpose of such functionality?  It looks like `d.ForEach(t => t.SomeBooleanProperty = false)` Without any expression tree involving.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv We are trying to implement wrapper for the Linq2Db so we would be able to write unit tests

Comment: As one of the linq2db creators, I'm surprised that there is no such tag. It can be challenge to mock such case, so why do not use SQLite in-memory to "mock" database?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv because it never crossed my mind! thank you!!!

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv do you have any code samples or any other examples at hand?

Comment: Just point `DataConnection` to SQLite, and fill with data as you did that with list. Anyway if you are trying to mock `Set` - you have to mock just `Update` method. Then analyse expression tree and update List accordingly. There is no complete samples because never had idea to mock SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is looking for the answer to the original question :

```cs
public static List<T> Set<T, TV>(List<T> items, Expression<Func<T, TV>> extract, Expression<Func<T, TV>> update)
{
    // If the expression extract isn't member access
    if (extract.Body.NodeType != ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    var memberAccess = (MemberExpression)extract.Body;

    // If the member access don't target a property
    if(memberAccess.Member.MemberType != System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Property)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    var propertyInfo = (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo)memberAccess.Member;

    // If the property don't have a setter to be updated
    if(!propertyInfo.CanWrite)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();

    var compiledUpdate = update.Compile();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        propertyInfo.SetValue(item, compiledUpdate.DynamicInvoke(item));
    }
    return items;
}
```

And this manage only the question's case. If you want manage more edge case, you will need some adaptation. Expression is very powerfull, but also complex.